# Do I need the Me keyword in class modules?

Tags: excel, vba, class, oop

These two subs do the same thing when inside a class.

```
Sub DemoMe( )
    Me.AboutMe    ' Calls AboutMe procedure.
End Sub

Sub DemoMe( )
    AboutMe    ' Does the same thing.
End Sub
```

What is the point? Does the Me keyword do anything? What is the preferred way of an object accessing its own members?

Comment: Me, refers to the object it's coming from so `AboutMe` resides in the class.  If you had another instance, say this is `Class1`, you'd have dim c as Class1, as soon as you create an instance of Class1 in Class1, you need to tell the compiler which class you are using, the holding class or the instance created in, where, `me.class1.aboutme` would be logically valid.  You can also create, a class for each cell in a workbook, then you could refer to `A1`'s class from `B1`'s class.  Also, if there is a public function/sub called AboutMe, this also helps. :o)

Comment: A class creating an instance of itself inside itself? That I've never seen.

Comment: It perfectly normal for a class to create an instance of itself - think `Class1.Copy As Class1`.

Comment: @PBeezy of course, think about using classes for humans, then you could have a parent child, where clsHuman could be the parent with an array of clsHuman for their children.

Comment: It is useful to auto-complete code. When you type "Me." then you get a list of members of that class. Less typing, less accidents, encourages using self-documenting procedure names.  Like "ShowAboutMeDialog", doesn't take more effort to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tldr;** No, although there are situations where it can be useful.

---

From the VBA language specification ([5.3.1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/78bcb344-4966-4401-bb55-72729790ebee)):

> Each procedure that is a method has an implicit ByVal parameter called
>   the *current object* that corresponds to the target object of an
>   invocation of the method. The current object acts as an anonymous
>   local variable with procedure extent and whose declared type is the
>   class name of the class module containing the method declaration. For
>   the duration of an activation of the method the data value of the
>   current object variable is target object of the procedure invocation
>   that created that activation. The current object is accessed using the
>   **Me** keyword within the <procedure-body> of the method but cannot be
>   assigned to or otherwise modified.

That's all it is, just a "free" local variable that refers to the specific instance that the method is being called on.  This also happens to be the default context for the procedures during their invocation, so it can be omitted if the code is intended to operate on the current instance.  Although as @HansPassant points out in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887822/do-i-need-the-me-keyword-in-class-modules#comment96546386_54887822), it also allows the editor to bind to the interface and provide IntelliSense.

That said, there are a couple instances where you would either want to or have to use it (this is by no means an exhaustive list):

---

**Naming collisions:**

If your class has a member that "hides" a built-in VBA function, it can be used to make the scope explicit:

```
Public Property Get Left() As Long
    '...
End Property

Public Property Get Right() As Long
    '...
End Property

Public Property Get Width() As Long
    Width = Me.Right - Me.Left
End Property
```

---

**Equity Checks:**

```
Public Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
    If other Is Me Then
        Equals = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    '...
End Function
```

---

**Fluent Functions:**

This can be a useful pattern for compositing objects - you perform an action, then return the instance of the class so they can be "chained".  Excel's `Range` interface does this in a lot of cases:

```
Public Function Add(Value As Long) As Class1
    'Do whatever.
    Set Add = Me
End Function

Public Sub Foo()
    Dim bar As New Class1
    bar.Add(1).Add(1).Add 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Not any more than there are reasons to use `this` in Java, C#, or any other language: it's a reserved identifier that represents the current instance of the class - what you do with that is up to your imagination.

> *What is the preferred way of an object accessing its own members?*

Indeed, an object doesn't *need* the `Me` keyword to access it own public interface. Same as `this` in other languages, I'd even call it redundant. However it can sometimes be a good idea to explicitly qualify member calls with `Me`, especially when the class has a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute (e.g. any `UserForm`): referring to `UserForm1` in the code-behind of `UserForm1` yields a reference to *the default instance* of the class, whereas qualifying member calls with `Me` yields a reference to *the current instance* of that class.

**Accessing Inherited Members**

VBA user code can't do class inheritance, but a lot of VBA classes *do* have a base class. The members of `UserForm` when you're in the code-behind of `UserForm1`, and those of `Worksheet` when you're in the code-behind of `Sheet1`, aren't necessarily easy to find. But since the inherited members show up in *IntelliSense*/auto-complete, you can type `Me.` and browse a list of members inherited from the base class, members that you would otherwise need to know about in order to invoke.

> *A class creating an instance of itself inside itself? That I've never seen.*

You're missing out! I do this all the time, to enable referring to the object instance held by a `With` block, inside a **Factory Method** - like [this GridCoord class](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Battleship/blob/master/src/GridCoord.cls).

```
Public Function Create(ByVal xPosition As Long, ByVal yPosition As Long) As IGridCoord
    With New GridCoord
        .X = xPosition
        .Y = yPosition
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As IGridCoord
    Set Self = Me
End Property
```

Note that while the `GridCoord` class exposes a getter and a setter for both `X` and `Y` properties, the `IGridCoord` interface only exposes the getters. As a result, code written against the `IGridCoord` interface is effectively working with read-only properties.

Another use is to get the name of the class module, without needing to hard-code it. This is particularly useful when raising custom errors: just use `TypeName(Me)` for the `Source` of the error.

---

The **Builder Pattern** notoriously returns `Me`, which enables a "fluent API" design that makes it possible to write code that incrementally builds complex objects through chained member calls, where each member returns `Me` (except the final `Build` call, which returns the type of the class being built):

```
Dim thing As Something
Set builder = New ThingBuilder
Set thing = builder _
    .WithFoo(42) _
    .WithBar("test") _
    .WithSomething _
    .WithSomethingElse
    .Build
```

Answer (score 1):

@PBeezy :   In addition to my comment :

Me, refers to the object it's coming from so AboutMe resides in the class. If you had another instance, say this is Class1, you'd have dim c as Class1, as soon as you create an instance of Class1 in Class1, you need to tell the compiler which class you are using, the holding class or the instance created in, where, me.class1.aboutme would be logically valid. You can also create, a class for each cell in a workbook, then you could refer to A1's class from B1's class. Also, if there is a public function/sub called AboutMe, this also helps.

Class (clsPerson)

```
Public c1 As clsPerson
Public strPersonName As String

Public Function NAME_THIS_PERSON(strName As String)
    strPersonName = strName
End Function

Public Function ADD_NEW_CHILD(strChildName As String)
    Set c1 = New clsPerson
    c1.strPersonName = strChildName
End Function
```

Normal module

```
Sub test()

Dim c As New clsPerson

c.NAME_THIS_PERSON "Mother"
c.ADD_NEW_CHILD "Nathan"

Debug.Print c.strPersonName
Debug.Print c.c1.strPersonName

End Sub
```

Gives these results

```
Mother
Nathan
```

Comment: Read the 1st line!

Comment: Mark it down if you are that fussed by it, I am not fussed at all.  :o)

Comment: Great, hope you feel better about it now :o)